# Weak differentiability in first $n$ coordinates

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Assume we have $f \in W^{1, \infty}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R})$. Can we then deduce that the mapping $x \mapsto f(x, y)$ for almost every $y \in \mathbb{R}$ is weakly differentiable?

Intuitively, this seems "weaker" and thus true, but I can not at all see it when i look at the integral equation that belongs to the definition of weak differentiability. Maybe we can choose test functions whose support is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \lbrace y \rbrace$...

Comment: Maybe it's and overkill, but can we see it as a direct consequence of $f$ is Lipschitz in $\Omega$ if and only if $f \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, then apply Rademacher and then look at the section of $f$ for $a.e.$ $y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me discuss the case $n=1$ only.
Let me denote by $f_x$ the weak derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.
Let $\phi,\psi$ be two smooth test functions. Then
$$
-\iint f_x(x,y) \phi(x)\psi(y)dx\ dy=\iint f(x,y) \phi_x(x)\psi(y)dx\ dy,
$$
using Fubini on both sides gives
$$
\int \left( \int -f_x(x,y) \phi(x) + f(x,y) \phi_x(x)\ dx\right) \psi(y) \ dy = 0
$$
for all smooth $\psi$, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations
$$
\int -f_x(x,y) \phi(x) + f(x,y) \phi_x(x)\ dx = 0
$$
for almost all $y$, which is the desired weak differentiability of $x
\mapsto f(x,y)$ .